# Delete rows in loop For and using Delete

Tags: functions, files-and-directories, row

I want to delete several rows from file txt and I'm using this code

```
i = 24;   
For[n = 0, n < 5500, n += 50, a = Delete[data, {{i - 1 + n}, {i + n}, {i + 1+ n}, {i + 2 + n}, {i + 3 + n}, {i + 4 + n}}]]
```

But when I do this I only get result which only delete lasts row so in this case delete only row from 5473 to 5478 and the others rows are the same.

Comment: At each step in the loop,`a` gets a new value. Therefore, the final value of `a` will be `Delete[data, {{24 - 1 + 5450}, {24 + 5450}, {24 + 1+ 5450}, {24 + 2 + 5450}, {24 + 3 + 5450}, {24 + 4 + 5450}}]`.

Answer (score 1):

I will go ahead and also show you step by step how to do this without loops. You have `data`, and you want to delete the elements in specific positions and save the result in `a`. Let's see how it could go. First try

```
Range[-1, 4]
(*{-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4}*)
```

Looking at your code, this should be added to $24$.

```
24 + Range[-1, 4]
(*{23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28}*)
```

In the loop, you also had `n`, running from $0$ to $5450$ in steps of $50$. We can use `Table` to include it.

```
Table[n + 24 + Range[-1, 4], {n, Range[0, 5450, 50]}]
```

The output of `Table` should be modified a bit so that `Delete` will use it as intended. Try a combination of `Flatten` and `Partition`.

```
Partition[
Flatten[Table[i + 24 + Range[-1, 4], {i, Range[0, 5450, 50]}]], 1]
```

Now we can just use `Delete` with this and we should be done.

```
a = Delete[data, 
Partition[
Flatten[Table[i + 24 + Range[-1, 4], {i, Range[0, 5450, 50]}]], 
1]];
```

Did this do what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you require.

```
todelete = {};
For[n = 0, n < 5500, n += 50,
 todelete = {todelete,
   {{i - 1 + n}, {i + n}, {i + 1 + n}, {i + 2 + n}, {i + 3 + n}, {i + 4 + n}}}]
todelete = List /@ Flatten@todelete;
a = Delete[data, todelete]
```

or, alternatively

```
todelete = Fold[Join[#1,
    {{i - 1 + #2}, {i + #2}, {i + 1 + #2}, {i + 2 + #2}, {i + 3 + #2}, {i + 4 + #2}}] &,
  {}, Range[0, 5450, 50]];
a = Delete[data, todelete]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = Range[5550];

i = 24;

Delete[data, 
 Flatten[
  Table[{{i - 1 + n}, {i + n}, {i + 1 + n}, {i + 2 + n}, {i + 3 + n}, {i + 4 + n}}, {n, 0, 5500, 50}]
         , 1]
       ]
```